# Flattening a nested object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to convert JSON to the format below, I'm having a problem converting it back.

**Here is the current format**

```
[{
    "id": "5",
    "parentid": "0",
    "text": "Device Guides",
    "index": 0,
    "children": [{
        "id": "10",
        "text": "Grandstream GXP-21XX",
        "index": 0
    }, {
        "id": "11",
        "text": "Polycom Soundstation/Soundpoint",
        "index": 1
    }, {
        "id": "23",
        "text": "New Polycom",
        "index": 2
    }]
}, {
    "id": "6",
    "parentid": "0",
    "text": "Pre-Sales Evaluation",
    "index": 1,
    "children": []
}, {
    "id": "7",
    "parentid": "0",
    "text": "Router Setup Guides",
    "index": 2,
    "children": [{
        "id": "9",
        "text": "Sonicwall",
        "index": 0
    }, {
        "id": "12",
        "text": "Cisco",
        "index": 1
    }]
}, {
    "id": "9",
    "parentid": "7",
    "text": "Sonicwall",
    "index": 3,
    "children": []
}, {
    "id": "10",
    "parentid": "5",
    "text": "Grandstream GXP-21XX",
    "index": 4,
    "children": []
}, {
    "id": "11",
    "parentid": "5",
    "text": "Polycom Soundstation/Soundpoint",
    "index": 5,
    "children": []
}, {
    "id": "12",
    "parentid": "7",
    "text": "Cisco",
    "index": 6,
    "children": []
}]
```

**Here is the format I need it in:**

```
[{
    "id": "5",
    "parentid": "0",
    "text": "Device Guides",
    "index": "0"
}, {
    "id": "6",
    "parentid": "0",
    "text": "Pre-Sales Evaluation",
    "index": "0"
}, {
    "id": "7",
    "parentid": "0",
    "text": "Router Setup Guides",
    "index": "0"
}, {
    "id": "9",
    "parentid": "7",
    "text": "Sonicwall",
    "index": "0"
}, {
    "id": "10",
    "parentid": "5",
    "text": "Grandstream GXP-21XX",
    "index": "0"
}, {
    "id": "11",
    "parentid": "5",
    "text": "Polycom Soundstation\/Soundpoint",
    "index": "0"
}, {
    "id": "12",
    "parentid": "7",
    "text": "Cisco",
    "index": "0"
}]
```

Basically, I have to nest it for the script I'm using but the server is expecting to see it flattened, in the current format the 3rd object dimension starts with "children". I need to unnest children and keep the objects going like the format I need it in.

Comment: FYI, JSON is a [text format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).  What you have here is javascript literal notation or just a javascript data structure.  This is not JSON.

Comment: please define "unnest" to get a sensible answer.

Comment: Is that the inner content of an array? This isint valid JS neither it is valid JSON.

Comment: How are you getting the json???

Comment: I would enclose the second format in square brakets, just to make it valid;) Unnest is quite generic as term. To me the first object represent a tree and to "unnest" it, you have to define the type of "Visit" you have to perform on the tree (deep first, breadth first, posticipated, anticipated, hoping there are the names of them in english. What have you done till now?

Comment: @jfriend00 in the first sentence I stated I converted json to this format.

Comment: I was wrong, it appears to be a generic graph

Comment: @akonsu the last sentence defines what I mean by "unnest", I need to remove the 3rd dimension from this array.

Comment: @Deepu a RESTful server, it is getting sent to me in the format I need to convert it to, when I get the data from the server, I push all the data with parentid == id to a children dimension.

Comment: @StephenHarman - but your javascript doesn't show as an array.  Are you missing the `[` and `]` from your data definition?

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, that was a typo. I edited the post to include them. Thank you for catching that Eineki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A first solution, granted you don't want the resulting array to be sorted based on the id:

```
function visitor(graph) {
  var i, l,
  nodes=[],
  visited=[];

  function clone(n) {
     // improve the function yourself I'm lazy
     var i,l,
         props=["id","parentid","index","text"],
         result={};
     for (i = 0, l = props.length; i < l; i++) { 
        if (n[props[i]]) {
          result[props[i]]= n[props[i]];
        }
     }
     return result;
  }

  function helper (node) {
    var i, limit;
    if (visited.indexOf(node.id) == -1) {
      visited.push(node.id);
      nodes.push(clone(node));
      if( node.children) {
        for (i = 0, limit = node.children.length; i < limit; i++) {
          helper(node.children[i]);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  for (i = 0, l = graph.length; i < l; i++) {
    helper(graph[i]);
  }

  return nodes;
}

var graph =     [{
    "id": "5",
    "parentid": "0",
    "text": "Device Guides",
    "index": 0,
    "children": [{
        "id": "10",
        "text": "Grandstream GXP-21XX",
        "index": 0
    }, {
        "id": "11",
        "text": "Polycom Soundstation/Soundpoint",
        "index": 1
    }, {
        "id": "23",
        "text": "New Polycom",
        "index": 2
    }]
}, {
    "id": "6",
    "parentid": "0",
    "text": "Pre-Sales Evaluation",
    "index": 1,
    "children": []
}, {
    "id": "7",
    "parentid": "0",
    "text": "Router Setup Guides",
    "index": 2,
    "children": [{
        "id": "9",
        "text": "Sonicwall",
        "index": 0
    }, {
        "id": "12",
        "text": "Cisco",
        "index": 1
    }]
}, {
    "id": "9",
    "parentid": "7",
    "text": "Sonicwall",
    "index": 3,
    "children": []
}, {
    "id": "10",
    "parentid": "5",
    "text": "Grandstream GXP-21XX",
    "index": 4,
    "children": []
}, {
    "id": "11",
    "parentid": "5",
    "text": "Polycom Soundstation/Soundpoint",
    "index": 5,
    "children": []
}, {
    "id": "12",
    "parentid": "7",
    "text": "Cisco",
    "index": 6,
    "children": []
}];

nodes = visitor(graph);
```

And yes, I know, the helper function relay on side effects but I've scoped them into the visitor function to reduce harm and there is room for improvements (at least sorting the resulting array based on the id) but I will leave them to you

Comment: Thanks for saving my life.